# How can I store fs.readdir file.length result to global variable?

Tags: javascript, download, automation, nightwatch.js

Currently I am using Cucumber, Nightwatch and node.js. The test is trying to check the number of the files in Downloads directory, download new file, and again get the number of the files in the same directory and in the end, compare  2 numbers.

The issue here is that when I use this code, and try to store 'files.length' count in a variable (in the same .js, or in globals.js) and try to print it after - I get undefined. I tried a lot of modifications, but nothing was successful so far. 
By the way the count from the code bellow is printed correctly.
Can someone tell me how to store 'files.length' count in a variable?

```js
        countFilesBeforeDownload: async function () {
            const fs = require('fs');
            const dir = 'C:\\Users\\{User}\\Downloads';

            fs.readdir(dir, (err, files) => {
                console.log("COUNT FROM DOWNLOADS: " + files.length);
            });
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#globals_global

the global object

```
global.fileLength = files.length
```

The global object exposes a variety of useful properties about the environment. Also, this is the place where functions such as setImmediate and clearTimeout are located.